# Error while using findContours in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, contour, mat

I wanted to process a black and white image using findContours.

```
Mat frame= imread(argv[1]);
cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_BGR2GRAY);
threshold(frame,frame, 150, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
vector<vector<Point2f>> contours;
findContours(frame.clone(), contours, noArray(), CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, 
CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE , Point(0, 0));
```

But I am getting the below exception :

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (mtype == type0 || (((((mtype) & ((512
>   - 1) << 3)) >> 3) + 1) == ((((type0) & ((512 - 1) << 3)) >> 3) + 1) && ((1 << type0) & fixedDepthMask) != 0)) in create, file
>   /home/nvidia/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 2578 terminate
>   called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'   what(): 
>   /home/nvidia/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:2578: error: (-215)
>   mtype == type0 || (((((mtype) & ((512 - 1) << 3)) >> 3) + 1) ==
>   ((((type0) & ((512 - 1) << 3)) >> 3) + 1) && ((1 << type0) &
>   fixedDepthMask) != 0) in function create.

Image used to findContours:

[image]

.Any pointers on how to solve this issue would be highly appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran your code and found the problem. You are using a `cv::Point2f` to store the contours, while you should be using `cv::Point`. Just simply edit the 4th line to:

```
vector<vector<Point>> contours
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, changing from Point2f to Point solved the problem.

Comment: Good to hear! Maybe approve the answer?